# Javascript toggle visibility showing text underneath

Tags: javascript, php, html

When i click the `*****` it shows the api key underneath on a new line. What I'm trying to do is when i click the stars it will hide the stars and show apikey then can someone point me where i went wrong.

**My Image**:

[image: My Image]

**My Code:**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> API Access:<span class="badge badge-danger pull-right"><span onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">********</span>
    <div id="foo" style="display:none;"><span class="label label-info"><?php echo ( isset($userInfo['apikey']) && !empty($userInfo['apikey']) ? $userInfo['apikey'] : "No" ); ?></span></div>
    </span>
    </a>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    //-->
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do that in same span to view it in same line

try this

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
 <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
 API Access:
 <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right">
  <span onclick="toggle_visibility('e_1','e_2');"><span id="e_1">********</span><span id="e_2" style="display:none;">API_KEY</span></span>
 </span>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id_1,id_2) {
 var e_1 = document.getElementById(id_1);
 var e_2 = document.getElementById(id_2);
 if ( e_1.style.display==='inline-block' || e_1.style.display === '' ) {
  e_1.style.display = 'none';
  e_2.style.display = 'inline-block';
 } else {
  e_1.style.display = 'inline-block';
  e_2.style.display = 'none';
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can improve your code in several ways, and make it work as you want. I simplify the HTML structure and js, considering the function behavior when you call from the html node.

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
  API Access:
  <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right">
    <span onclick="show_apikey(<?php echo ( isset($userInfo['apikey']) && !empty($userInfo['apikey']) ? $userInfo['apikey'] : "No" ); ?>);">********</span>
  </span>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function show_apikey(apikey) {
  this.innerText = apikey;
}
//-->
</script>
```